# Stock Ubuntu images in Digital Ocean cloud

Tags: repository, cloud

Recently I came across a discussion where a commentator [pointed out](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11937501) that OVH uses modified Ubuntu images in their cloud service. That means that when I choose to deploy an Ubuntu image on OVH cloud I won't have an original Ubuntu.

I am currently client of Digital Ocean (DO) where I have Ubuntu deployed. I have noticed in the sources.list file some DO repositories (preceded by a warning comment `ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu team`) . I understand that they have mirrors to speed updates and limit their bandwidth use, but I am concerned about the originality of the images I am using, thus my question: How I make sure the packages I am using come really from Ubuntu's packages? Is modifying the sources.list files sufficient to have the right packages?

Note: DO has  had in the past a [security problem](https://missingm.co/2013/07/identical-droplets-in-the-digitalocean-regenerate-your-ubuntu-ssh-host-keys-now/), due (in my understanding) to the cloud images they use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only public clouds that receive official Ubuntu images are listed on this page: http://partners.ubuntu.com/programmes/public-cloud

Currently Digital Ocean is not on that list, so there's no way for us to confirm that you're getting an official image.